# MySQL triggers + setting variables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am having an issue when using a trigger to pull information from other tables in order to insert them  when I do an insert for a particular relation.  This is basically to save me from having to look up information in other tables that I'll need for my relation.  The issue is that I am having problems setting a variable equal to the results of a query then using the value in that variable to set one of the columns in my table.  The code looks like so.  The problem is that my variable is never getting set it is always null but I can perform the query from the command line and get a result so I am not really sure what the issue is could someone please point out what I am doing wrong.

It is worth noting the relations sales_cost has 2 members model(primary key) VARCHAR(45) and price FLOAT

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`local`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `mydb`.`sales_contract_before`
BEFORE INSERT ON `mydb`.`sales_contract`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

/*variables*/
declare cost float;

/*
SELECT car.model INTO model FROM car where car.id = NEW.car_id;
set NEW.model = model;*/

 set cost = (select price from sales_cost where model = NEW.model);  //cost never gets set its always null


set new.price = cost;

END$$
```

UPDATE: 
I seem to have figured out what the issue was but still would like some insight (if anyone has it as to how to accomplish this) the issue is in using the WHERE qualifier for some reason if I use a WHERE in any set query regardless of the table i am selecting from it just doesn't return (or returns NULL).  What i did was created a function that takes in the model name and then returns the cost by doing the same query.  But if anyone could give an example on how to set a variable equal to the result of a query with a where that works I'd really be grateful.  I think it must be a syntax error on my part but I don't really know enough about triggers to venture a guess as to the issue

Comment: no i don't think it is its the value is still null after I try and set cost ( I get an error when trying to use it). I mean that I can use the same query from the CL and get a result so I know there is something in the table that corresponds to that query but its failing to set the variable in  the trigger for some reason

Comment: are you sure the query returns only one result? and please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: The error I get is from trying to insert into the table the value cost which is null because it never gets set it says error column 'price' cannot be null. Also yes it only returns 1 result I am positive I tested it through CL and workbench

Comment: Edit your answer and add your sales_contract table structure and Insert statement that you are using.

Comment: This is a confirmed "Serious" bug since 2004; patch pending, no update for two years.  See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6295.  Don't hold your breath.

Comment: @cpowel2  Add your sales_contract table structure and Insert statement and tell me what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to set multi variable with select query like this

```
DECLARE var1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE var2 DATE;
BEGIN
Select id,date From table_name Where id=Id
INTO var1,var2;
END;
```